# Mockito throwing NPE in Spring test class @BeforeAll method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, nullpointerexception, mockito

I'm trying to mock a service using Mockito and setting up all the method invocations in a @BeforeAll method. The code is the following:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public class VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests {

    @MockBean
    static VirtualMachineService virtualMachineService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    static String courseId;
    static String studentId;
    static Long teamId;
    static Long vmId;
    static SystemImage os;
    static VirtualMachineDTO virtualMachineDTO;
    static ConfigurationDTO configurationDTO;


    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {
        studentId = "student";
        courseId = "course";
        teamId = 1L;
        vmId = 1L;
        os = SystemImage.WINDOWS_10;
        virtualMachineDTO = VirtualMachineDTO.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .num_vcpu(2)
                .disk_space(1000)
                .ram(4)
                .status(VirtualMachineStatus.OFF)
                .build();
        configurationDTO = ConfigurationDTO.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .min_vcpu(2)
                .min_disk(1000)
                .min_ram(4)
                .max_vcpu(12)
                .max_disk(2000)
                .max_ram(16)
                .max_on(4)
                .tot(20)
                .build();

        Mockito.when(Mockito.any(VirtualMachineService.class).createVirtualMachine(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyLong(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(virtualMachineDTO);
    }
}
```

The NPE is throwed by Mockito even without the `thenReturn` method. If I move this line

```
 Mockito.when(Mockito.any(VirtualMachineService.class).createVirtualMachine(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyLong(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(virtualMachineDTO);
```

inside a @Test method then, after throwing a NPE, it will output this:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at it.polito.ai.backend.VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests.createVirtualMachine(VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests.java:87)
-> at it.polito.ai.backend.VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests.createVirtualMachine(VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests.java:87)
-> at it.polito.ai.backend.VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests.createVirtualMachine(VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests.java:87)
-> at it.polito.ai.backend.VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests.createVirtualMachine(VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests.java:87)
-> at it.polito.ai.backend.VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests.createVirtualMachine(VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests.java:87)
-> at it.polito.ai.backend.VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests.createVirtualMachine(VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests.java:87)
-> at it.polito.ai.backend.VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests.createVirtualMachine(VirtualMachineServiceIntegrationTests.java:87)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

I'm new at Spring testing and Mockito so I cannot figure it out what I'm doing wrong. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things a bit strange here. The main/misunderstanding problem is:

Mockito#when is used to tell a **concrete mock** what to do on specific method call.
So normally it goes something like this:

```
Mockito.when(mock.doSomeThings(anyString()).thenReturn("whatever");
```

Applying this pattern to your code, this should do the trick:

```
Mockito.when(virtualMachineService.createVirtualMachine(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyLong(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any Int(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(virtualMachineDTO);
```

Besides this, it looks strange to that you declared everything as static.
I would remove static from all class members and change `@BeforeAll` to `@Before` or `@BeforeEach` (depending on if you use JUnit 4 or 5).